# Trying to compile simple c++ program in make

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cygwin

I am having trouble with make. I installed all of the features that come with cygwin. When I type in `make` command it says:

> make:***No targets specified and no
>   makefile found. Stop.

This is really annoying as it's a very simple program. 
My make file (Makefile):

```
# This is a sample file.

all: lab1

lab1: lab1.o
 g++ -Wall lab1.o -o lab1

lab1.o: lab1.cpp
 g++ -Wall -c lab1.cpp -o lab1.o
```

my program (lab1.cpp):

```
// This is a sample file written.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Welcome to CS-240!" << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your code and Makefile to be more readable?  Also, is your Makefile named exactly that?  Are you in the directory where the Makefile is when you run `make`?

Comment: Looks like `make` is not able to find your `Makefile`. Check the directory you are running `make` at.

Comment: i am in the directory (when i do ls, it lists those 2 files). My makefile is named: Makefile

Comment: Are the spaces before `g++` in your Makefile actually tabs?  There needs to be exactly one tab (not expanded into spaces) before each command.  That isn't the error you're getting, though.  What is the path to your Makefile?  What does `pwd` print out (in Bash) when you try to run `make`?

Comment: Again, I AM in the correct directory where my makefile is and my source code. I am using cygwin on windows 7

Comment: Makefile, without leading or trailing space?

Comment: tabs are there formatting is as normal.

Comment: btw. when i do ls command, it lists: "Makefile.mak" and "lab1.cpp"

Comment: exactly "Makefile" is the filename.

Comment: The Makefile needs to be named "Makefile", not "Makefile.mak".  Use `mv` to change its name to remove the extension.

Comment: why does notepadd++ add that extension to make files? Are they retarded?

Comment: So I'm assuming then that you fixed your earlier problems with actually getting `make` installed. I'd be interested to know what the problem _was_ (and, of course, you should vote-up/accept those answers that helped).

Comment: yes sorry. I will vote up. The problem was that i didnt have all the make features installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (fixed in the comments) was that there was a `Makefile.mak` in the directory but not an actual `Makefile` without an extension.  Changing the name worked for the submitter.